# Changing the version in the info.plist file so that correct version will show up in mac finder

Tags: macos, version, finder, info.plist

I am doing maintenance on app that other people created and I want to change the version in the Info.plist file so that when  someone selects the app in the finder the correct version will show up.  When I manually edit the info.plist file and change the bundle version string from 1.0 to 3.0 it still display 1.0 in the finder.  Also, when I recompile the app the version string gets set to 1.0.  Can anyone direct me to some info about how these kinds of variables get set and how the info.plist gets created or setup.  I don't really know much about the info.plist and have not found any good resources online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for an entry named `CFBundleGetInfoString`. The value of this entry is a string which the Finder displays in the info window. You should set the `CFBundleShortVersionString` to the same version you mention in the info string.

Comment: ... and it's documented here http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html

Comment: There are no references to CFBundleGetInfoString in the entire project (this is likely why it is version 1.0).  Where would these variables normally be set?  Would I do this in an xml and include that with the project?

Comment: The CFBundleGetInfoString is an entry in the Info.plist file of the bundle in question, in this case the application. You said, you edited the Info.plist file to change the bundle version. Setting the CFBundleGetInfoString works the same way.

Comment: CFBundleGetInfoString is now obsolete. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html